# How to return a key of a dictionary based on sorting its values in a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let's say

```
dict = {
    'a': [(10, 10), (5, 5), (1, 100)],
    'b': [(1, 10), (5, 10)]
}
```

I would like to return 'a' because the list for that key contains the tuple with the smallest value in the second element;

(5, 5) has 5 as its second element, which is smaller than the second element of all other tuples.

I have tried using `min()` on the list of tuples, but `min` sorts based on the first element, and only looks at the second element if there are "ties".

Answer (score 3):

You can use `min` with `key` and find `min` value on `tuple`s in
`list` and return `key of dict` with `min` value:

```
dct = {'a': [(10, 10), (5, 5), (1, 100)], 
       'b': [(1, 10),  (5, 10)],
       'c': [(100, 1), (10,10)]}
             
min(dct, key=lambda x: min(tpl[1] for tpl in dct[x]))
# 'c'
```